# Named Object Property Functions

Tags: javascript

```js
render: function render(context, partials) {
  return this.r(context, partials);
},
```

Given this code from Twitter's new hogan.js library to demonstrate the issue; what is the goal of naming the function twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it wanted to, the function `render` would be able to [call itself via `render()`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqqs6/), however, `render()` is not accessible [anywhere else](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqqs6/1/).

Additionally, in a stack trace, you'd see `render` as the function name, rather than `anonymous function`.

Comment: It also has to be said that there is a bug in older IE versions, namely that it will generate two different functions for named function expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation; it's a pattern that I've been mystified by for a couple of months now.

Comment: This is also required in strict mode since `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee` both throw on read, and therefore the function actually needs to be named in order to call itself.

Comment: @Frédéric: With this setup yes, but if the function is accessible in the enclosing scope, then it could still call itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's needed for a recursive call.

Comment: It's not *needed* but it can be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

The first occurance of *render* is the name of the field the function is stored in, so that you can call the function via

```
object.render(context, partials);
```

The second *render* names the function itself. Debugging tools then display *render* instead of only *function*.

A second, possible reason is that the function could call itself recursively.

```
var render = function render(n) {
    console.log("render");
    if (n < 1)
      render(n + 1);
};
render(0);
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I've written something really wrong in the first revision.